# Save ml.feature.LabeledPoint to local libsvm file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, libsvm

The (almost legacy) mllib LabeledPoint is saved to libsvm file as follows:

```
val rddtoprint:RDD[LabeledPoint]= ....

MLUtils.saveAsLibSVMFile(rddtoprint, s"$newPath${File.separator}${fileName }")
```

What would be the equivalent method for ml.feature.LabeledPoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so there are two options.
1. just do it yourself. Generate as a String and save using standard File IO

```
  def libSVMFileAsString():String= {

    val sparse0=internalCheckColumnOrder()

    val rows:Array[String]=sparse0.lpData().map { case LabeledPoint(label, features) =>
      val sb = new StringBuilder(label.toString)
      features.foreachActive { case (i, v) =>
        sb += ' '
        sb ++= s"${i + 1}:$v"
      }
      sb.mkString
    }.collect()

    val sbOut:mutable.StringBuilder=new mutable.StringBuilder()
    rows.foreach(r=>sbOut.append(r + "\n"))
    sbOut.toString()
  }
```

2. Convert to dataframe and then save:

   ```
   def labeledPintsAsDataFrame(): DataFrame =
   {
      lpData:RDD[LabeledPoint]=...
      val sqlContext = spark.sqlContext
      import sqlContext.implicits._
      lpData().toDF
   }
   ```

and then

```
dftoprint.write.format("libsvm").save(s"$newPath${File.separator}${fileName}")
```

Answer (score 1):

At least as early as Spark 2.2, there is a helper method within MLUtils.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/mllib/util/MLUtils.html